# why Loopj library works fine on the android emulator and doesn't run on real device?

Tags: android, json, httprequest, loopj

I use this library (http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) to download a json from my website, in the emulator works fine but when I try in a real device does not work (tablet and smartphone) it doesn't enter in the function onSuccess.
Someone can tell me why or what am I forgetting?

Comment: do you have internet access on your device ?

Comment: Yes, I tried in the phone and the tablet..
Here there's the functino
http://pastebin.com/wjgReW2D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into this issue myself on several devices and it is most likely the same as reported here by many people, which is still open after some months:

https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/144

Personally I switched to http://code.google.com/p/basic-http-client/ which I have had lots of success with.

Not exactly a direct fix to the problem but still.